# How to get from Rovaniemi to Trondheim under the corona crisis?

Tags: international-travel, norway, covid-19, finland, finnish-citizens

How does one get from Rovaniemi, Finland, to Trondheim, Norway, without a car?

- Finnish citizen residing permanently Norway, with pictures of relevant documents and a passport at hand.
- Not in a terrible hurry.

Some possibilities:

- Can one fly from Helsinki to Oslo or Trondheim after taking a train to Helsinki? The flights are booked full for about a week, which is not ideal.
- Is there a way of getting to Troms/Tromsø/Tromssa and can one fly on (or even take a bus) from there?
- Is it possible to pass through Sweden? A ship from Vaasa/Vasa or some method the cross the border at Tornio/Torneå are possible ways of getting into Sweden, if it is possible.
- Is there a functional way of finding people travelling the same route or part of it by private car?

Comment: As of right now, trains and buses seem to run more or less as usual on this route (train from Rovaniemi to Kemi, bus to Luleå and then train to Trondheim). Transit through Sweden should be possible and you will be quarantined for 14 days when arriving in Norway. This information may however already be outdated later today. Things change very rapidly.